# How do I discover what my service's dependencies are?

Tags: delphi, windows-services, dependencies

I have a Windows service that uses:

- Midas.dll (datasnap ClientDataSet)
- Indy components (TCP and FTP)
- DbExpress
- CreateProcessAsUser
- Handles to make IPC

At some machines (with old hardware and Windows XP) it hangs up during the start.

Checking the Windows event logs, I found events IDs: **7022**, **7036**.

After the machine boot, I start the service manually and everything goes fine!

I think the problem is related to missing dependencies on my service.

My question is:

**How can I find the necessary dependencies for my service?**

**Is there some utility to tell me this?**

---

**UPDATE**

I already have logs...

My service is pluggable by some "sub-services" that I call as plugins. This plugins starts with a "plugin manager", an application (exe) what loads the dll to garantee the service memory isolation.

This plugin manager has an Handle (AllocateHWnd) to be abble to receive messages (via sendmessange) from the service, like:

- start
- reload plugin library
- stop

The bootstrap of the plugin manager is:

- start and send a message to the handle of the service (passed via parameter) to send back to the service the handle allocated internaly (by plugin manager) for IPC between service and plugin manager.

The bootstrap code at the service, what launches the plugin manager, is:

```
start := now;
while callbackHandle = 0 do
begin
  if PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then
  begin
    // need to process a message on WndProc to
    // assign the 'callbackHandle' variable with the
    // handle sent from the plugin manager
    TranslateMessage(msg);
    DispatchMessage(msg);
  end;

  // timeout! Plugin manager doesn't  sent it's handle!!
  if secondsBetween(now, start) > 60 then
     break;
end;

if callbackHandle = 0 then
  raise Exception.Create('Cannot receive the callback handle from plugin manager');
```

At the logs, the exception above occurs: Cannot receive the callback handle from plugin manager

Seems that the service handle doesn't receives the pluginmanager handle, to start the IPC (inter process communication).

The bizarre thing is, if I start manually the service after the computer's boot, it starts normally.

Comment: The easiest way to start would be to implement a logging mechanism in your service. Simply write everything you are doing into a `TextFile`. Then, you can easily find out where does your service hang.

Comment: Most likely you are trying to do internet/TCP/IP stuff before the system is ready. How about you delay operation for a while, and see if that fixes it. Alternatively, set a dependency on something basic.

Comment: Check again your logs. Is the message sent? at which time? maybe you have to adjust your wait time, since the system is booting, maybe the other part takes more than 60 seconds to send the message, but sure your logs can tell you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message queue processing time wasn't the problem.
The problem was: slow hardware

I increased the [ServicePipeTimeout](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839803) from 30 seconds (default) to 2 minutes and everything comes fine again.

Now I will try to use the  [RequestAdditionalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx) at the service OnStart event. The only problem is that I'm using Delphi 7.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to start would be to implement a logging mechanism in your service. Simply write everything you are doing into a `TextFile`. Then, you can easily find out where does your service hang.

What are you connecting to with `DBExpress`? A database engine like SQL Server? If that's the case, perhaps your service is being started before the RDBMS...

Comment: The question doesn't ask for guesses of what might be wrong. It asks for a technique or tool that will discover what the dependencies are.